# Is it possible to create an OS that can run all application?

Tags: operating-system, cross-platform

Just a thought, if we have to make our application cross-platform, then is it possible to create a cross-application OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically yes as long as you limit the scope of **all** to all applications that run on major OSes.

It is theoretically possible to create an OS that could handle applications run on the 4-5 most common OSes but the amount of work involved would be monumental.

Every time a new feature was added to any of the OSes, you'd need to add it to your OS too - So as well as being almost impossible to build, you'd need a large enough dev team to stay ahead of 4-5 of the largest dev teams/groups in the world.

Comment: So to summarise: In theory? Yes. In Practise? No.

Comment: @Plasticfile *ahem* That's "Binary Worrier", not Wormer :)

Comment: @Binary Worrier LMAO Touche and my apologies. I hadn't had my coffee

Answer (score 2):

No.

Lets say you do go and invest - a monumental amount of - effort in building you're Uber-OS (that will run Mac apps, Linux apps, Unix apps, Android apps, i-phone apps, Nokia apps, Symbian apps, SAP apps, Windows Apps etc).

Then there's nothing stopping someone writing a new OS that you don't support.

P.S. And there are hundreds (if not thousands) of different hand held devices out there for scanning products, weights and mesures etc many of which have their own flavour of OS.

Comment: Well to be fair there's nothing to stop him from adding support to Uber-OS for ScrewOverUber-OS OS applications.

Comment: Then I'll create a 'HaHa' OS with many hidden, hard to find features :) *Everytime you make a system idiot proof, the universe creates a better idiot*

Comment: Fair enough sir, fair enough.  I was just trying to talk about in theory though.  Theoretically there's nothing to stop it, but it goes against all practicality and could only exist in the real world if all OSes began to homogenize.

Comment: @user: Even if OSes began to homogenize, you'd still have a _huge_ pile of legacy applications...

Comment: Yes but as hard as it is to work with the legacy applications it would still be possible and there wouldn't really be any future problems so once you were done with the legacy you'd pretty much be done. Is even that impractical? Incredibly. But it'd be much more doable without having to account for future unknowns.

Comment: "But it'd be much more doable", yes, much more doable in that you have only one infinity of work to do, not 10 infinities, so in that way, yes it is much less work.

Answer (score 1):

No but with virtualization you could have a single *computer* that can run any application.

Answer (score 1):

First there is the practical impossibility of successfully following the evolution of an indefinite number of operating systems. Do we take embedded OS into account? How about one-shot OS for specific applications? How about proprietary OS with no access to documentation?

Then there is also the - very difficult, if not impossible - problem of merging the various paradigms used in the wild. Ideally you would want OS services like the clipboard, or networking or ... or ... to work in a uniform way and allow applications to cooperate as if targeted to the same OS.

(Let's not even think about the various hardware-dependent applications.)

After all this, you should also consider what the application development for your own OS would be like...

I wonder if this is a good case for [Gödel's incompleteness theorems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godel%27s_incompleteness_theorems) :-)

PS: That said, there are quite a few projects attempting to bridge the various OS gaps:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_system_emulators

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_emulators#Operating_System_emulators

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use virtual machines, such as [VMWare's](http://www.answers.com/topic/vmware) software, and emulate several operating systems on the same physical machine.

Answer (score 0):

What do you define by an operating system that can run **all** applications?

Applications are mostly written in a higher level language and then translated into binary code that differs between machine architectures (like Intel and PowerPC) and operating systems (like Windows or Unix-based systems).

Java for example is only cross-platform because not the language itself is cross-platform (any high level language is), but because there exist Java virtual machines for different architectures and operating systems that abstract the heterogeneity of the underlying system.

It is definitely not theoretically impossible (nothing is except for some mathematical problems), but can you imagine what one would have to do in order to make such a thing work? You can basically run Linux programs in Windows with CygWin, you can also run Windows programs in Linux with Wine. All of those try to create a small operating system (e.g. the Windows core) into your other OS (e.g. Linux). This is probably not what you want.

To summarize, I can't imagine anyone really trying to do that. With all the money in the world, seriously. Better invest in writing native apps for the operating systems you want to support.